# Is there an online tool for JSON values anonymization (to replace real values with random ones)?

Tags: web-apps, json, hosted, anonymization

I have an issue with generating client code from an OpenAPI JSON file and I have posted a question about it. However, I have to post the JSON and I have to anonymize it (replace real values with some random ones) and I cannot seem to find any online tool to do this.

**Question:** Is there an online tool for JSON values anonymization (to replace real values with random ones)?